# Creating SQL Indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in my database that look roughly like this:

Communication: (Calls made)

```
Timestamp            FromIDNumber ToIDNumber GeneralLocation 
2012-03-02 09:02:30  878          674        Grasslands 
2012-03-02 11:30:01  456          213        Tundra 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  789          654        Mountains
```

Movement:

```
Timestamp            IDNumber Type        X   Y  
2012-03-02 11:02:30  379      pedestrian  32  46
2012-03-01 12:32:41  654      pedestrian  54  56
2012-03-02 07:02:16  789      pedestrian  39  52
```

and I want to run this query:

```
SELECT c.senderID, c.timestamp, m.timestamp, m.x, m.y
FROM communication c
JOIN movement m 
ON c.senderID = m.visitorID
WHERE m.timestamp >= c.timestamp
ORDER BY m.timestamp LIMIT 1;
```

Basically, I want to find the closest movement timestamp to a given communication timestamp.

The thing is, these tables have millions of entries and I need to use indexes. The problem is, I'm new to SQL, and I'm not sure exactly how to structure my indexes.... would I need to have one for m.timestamp and c.timestamp separately like this?

```
CREATE INDEX mtstamp ON DBName.movement (timestamp); 

CREATE INDEX ctstamp ON DBName.communication (timestamp);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a composite index that includes both the ID that you're using in the `JOIN` and the timestamp. Otherwise, it will just use the ID indexes for the join, but it will then have to scan all the matching rows to do the timestamp comparisons.

```
CREATE INDEX sender_timestamp ON communication (senderID, timestamp);
CREATE INDEX visitor_timestamp ON movement (visitorID, timestamp);
```

Comment: Oh... So I should basically create indexes for `m.timestamp`,`c.timestamp`,`c.senderID`,`m.visitorID`, and the composite that you posted? Do you just use composite indexes when you're using a statement that needs columns from two tables?

Comment: You don't need indexes on `senderID` and `visitorID`, because a prefix of a composite index can also be used as an index by itself.

Comment: I see thanks so much! So then I just edited my question, my indexes should be structured like that, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would create an index on `timestamp` on both table since that column is used in `WHERE` condition to filter out rows as well as in `ORDER BY` for sorting.

Also, create an index on `senderID` in `Communication` table and `visitorID` in `Movement` table unless those are primary key column on the respective table; since those two columns are involved in join condition.